# Getting wait timeout exception for page.navigate("someURLWhichIsAccessableFromPod") method within the docker pod

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, gui-testing, playwright-java

I have written one test case using playwright, which will open one web page using **`page.navigate()`** method and once it is loaded it will do further testing on opened web page.

Here the issue i am getting is on `"page.navigate()"` method where it is not able to load the webpage url and getting waiting timeout exception.

As a base image here i am using **`"<base.docker.image>mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/java:v1.34.0-jammy</base.docker.image>"`**

Note, below things I have tried :

1. The URL which the test case is trying to open, that URL is accessible within the docker pod checked it using **"curl"** command.
2. Also tried to increase the default wait timeout till 5 minutes.
3. On my local machine the same test case is running successfully, this issue is specific to only docker pod.

`import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser;
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserContext;
import com.microsoft.playwright.BrowserType;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;


public class PlayWrightTestSetup {

   
    // Shared between all tests in the class.
    public static Playwright playwright;
    public static Browser browser;

    // New instance for each test method.
    public static BrowserContext context;
    public static Page page;

    
    @BeforeSuite()
    public void setUpTestSuite() {
        playwright = Playwright.create();
        browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(Boolean.TRUE));
        
    }

    @AfterSuite()
    public void testSuitePostStep() {
            playwright.close();
    }

}



import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class TestClass extends PlayWrightTestSetup {

    @BeforeMethod()
    public void createContextAndPage() {
      
        context = browser.newContext(new Browser.NewContextOptions().setIgnoreHTTPSErrors(true));
        context.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(90000);
        
    }

    @AfterMethod()
    public void closeContext() {
       context.close();
    }
    
    @Test()
    public void testUI(){
        Page someUIPage = context.newPage();
        LOGGER.info("Opening web page...");
        someUIPage.navigate("www.testexample.com",new Page.NavigateOptions().setWaitUntil(WaitUntilState.LOAD));
        LOGGER.info("Successfully loaded web page");
    }
    
}


Error :
navigating to "https://www.testexample.com/", waiting until "load"
============================================================   name='TimeoutError   stack='TimeoutError: Timeout 90000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs =========================== navigating to "https://www.testexample.com/", waiting until "load"
============================================================
    at ProgressController.run (/tmp/playwright-java-1873968284753476751/package/lib/server/progress.js:88:26)
    at Frame.goto (/tmp/playwright-java-1873968284753476751/package/lib/server/frames.js:521:23)
    at FrameDispatcher.goto (/tmp/playwright-java-1873968284753476751/package/lib/server/dispatchers/frameDispatcher.js:75:121)
    at DispatcherConnection.dispatch (/tmp/playwright-java-1873968284753476751/package/lib/server/dispatchers/dispatcher.js:312:46)`

Comment: Please share the relevant code along with errors.

Comment: Hi @VishalAggarwal thanks you for your response,  i have added the code snippet along with error logs

Comment: You can also enable https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer to see what is going on under the hood on the page however likely won't able to share here on public space.

Comment: Does this happen on any specific browser like firefox or chrome?

Comment: trace-viewer help me to check network calls , where i found one external call which is not accessible within pod @VishalAggarwal Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Wait for navigation

I think it's sync issue as it works in local.

Playwright being very fast after navigation it immediately expects for load to complete.

> Modern web applications  perform numerous activities after the load
> event was fired. They fetch data lazily, populate UI, load expensive
> resources, scripts and styles after the load event was fired. It's
> hard to tell actually when the page load is complete.

So please *explicitly* wait for an element after navigation which *only becomes visible* once page load is *fully* complete. You may do this visually by observing the page load and identify an element which loads at the last:

```
page.navigate("https://example.com");

assertThat(page.getByText("Welcome")).isVisible();
```

Comment: Tried with above solution , getting same error

Comment: Please try reducing the workers count to 1 , that may also help sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

trace-viewer help me to check network calls , where i found one external call which is not accessible within pod @VishalAggarwal Thank you :)